# Facebook Android SDK FeedDialog Hashtag

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I use the Facebook FeedDialog to Publish a Link on the Users Wall. I use the FaceBook AndroidSDK. I set these Parameters for the FeedDialog:

```
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("caption",getString(R.string.app_name));`
parameters.putString("name", titleTmp);
parameters.putString("link", urlTmp);
```

But I couldn't find a way to prefill the Text what the user can type, to inert a new Facebook HashTag. Is this possible?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot prefill the text, it's against policy. The user must type in their own message. There's also no hashtag support for the feed dialog.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I already detected, that Facebook removed this feature recently because of some policies. I'll send a feature request, I think I'm not the only one who need this feature.

Comment: @ming-li. You just borke my heart sir. Yeah, hashtag should be supported on feed dialog